# find list of differences in two text files batch script

Tags: batch-file

Hers is what I am trying to do.  I have LISTa(data.txt) which contains a list of data and LISTb(has.txt) which contains another list of data.  I want to compare LISTa(data.txt) to LISTb(has.txt) and to determine what from LISTa(data.txt) is not in LISTb(has.txt).  I have tried the following with no success.  I think it is because both list contain numbers.

```
Findstr /ivg:"%home%\has.txt" "%home%\data.txt" > %home%\final.txt
```

But all i get is a blank list

I have gotten it to work with the following code but want to know if there is something that is easier as when completed this will be comparing thousands of lines in the lists

```
for /f %%a in (%home%\has.txt) do CALL :sub1 %%a


GOTO EOF
:sub1
ECHO IN sub1
findstr /iv "%1" "%home%\data.txt" > %home%\final.txt
del %home%\data.txt /q
rename %home%\final.txt data.txt    
exit /b
```

Comment: what about `FC` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Findstr /b /e /ivg:"%home%\has.txt" "%home%\data.txt" > %home%\final.txt
```

should see you right. It makes sure that the matches are made against the entire line so `123` in `data.txt` doesn't match `2` in `has.txt`.

Comment: Thanks.  This is fast and easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Load lines from data.txt
for /F %%a in (%home%\data.txt) do set line[%%a]=1

rem Delete lines from has.txt
for /F %%a in (%home%\has.txt) do set "line[%%a]="

rem Show the rest, that is, lines in data.txt that was not in has.txt
(for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%a) > %home%\final.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.  Used this code to perform a different function faster